# Получить текст, который не находится внутри HTML тега с помощью PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, синтаксический-анализ

Вот такая ситуация. Мне нужно парсить HTML страницу с помощью Simple HTML DOM библиотеки. Есть такой фрагмент:

> `<br/>
>
>   <br/>
>
>   <b>Название:< /b>
>
>   Имя файла
>
>   <br/>
>
>   <br/>`

Мне нужно извлечь "Имя файла". А он, как видите, не находится в каком либо теге.

Comment: @Alexof, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Не надо извращаться так, тут есть нужный инструмент.

Comment: извиняюсь. не знал о ней.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$data = <<<HTML
< br/>
< br/>
< b>Название:< /b>
Название файла
< br/>
< br/>
HTML;
$html=str_get_html($data);

$html->find("b",0)->outertext="";
echo $html->plaintext;
```

только ваше:

```
< br/>
< br/>
< b>Название:< /b>
Название файла
< br/>
< br/>
```

не похоже на HTML, незнаю найдет ли элемент < b> ваша библиотека. Просто пробел перед названием элемента смущает!

Comment: ну, пробелы не нужны (см. вопрос (редактировал чуток))

Comment: спасибо за попитку помочь! отличие между innertext i outertext в том, что первый выдает найденное без тегов (Название:), а второй с тегами(< b>Название:< /b>). так что наверное здесь придется регулярить :/

Comment: Так эту строку можно удалить вот так:

    $html->find("b",0)->outertext="";

после останеться:

    < br/>
    < br/>
    Название файла
    < br/>
    < br/>

в итоге:

    $html->plaintext;

будет содержать искомое...

Comment: мммм да. чет похожее но не $html->plaintext; а $html->save();

Answer (score 1):

А зачем Вам DOM?
В данном случае - проще regexp`ами:

```
$data = <<<HTML
< br/>
< br/>
< b>Название:< /b>
Название файла
< br/>
< br/>
HTML;
preg_match('#< /b>([^\<]*)< br/>#isU', $data, $matches);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($matches);
echo '</pre>';
$fn = trim($matches[1]);
echo 'File name: '. $fn;
```

Comment: может быть))) но думал может кто знает на DOM )

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что либа DOM написана именно для извлечения элементов дерева DOM со страницы, а у Вас, увы этот текст не является частью объектной модели HTML