# preg_match php - не понимаю

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
<p><span>Ширина</span>: от 300 мм  до 1000 мм.</p>
<p><span>Высота</span>: до 2500 мм.</p>
<p><span>Срок изготовления</span>: 3 - 5 дней.</p>
```

Сделал паттерн для php:

```
"/<p>.*<//p>/g"
```

Но функция `preg_match` ничего не находит. подскажите пожалуйста что я делаю не так?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/80220/%d0%9f%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b3-html-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-php тут есть ответ на ваш вопрос?

Comment: @Naumov не увидел. решение тут подсказали.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `preg_match` не понимает модификатора `g`, вместо этого, чтобы найти все вхождения, нужно использовать `preg_match_all`
2. экранировать нужно обратным слешем

Итого:

```
preg_match_all('/<p>.*<\/p>/', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

либо, если вам нужно только то что внутри тега `p`:

```
preg_match_all('/<p>(.*)<\/p>/', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

**update**

Полезное дополнение из комментария: парсить HTML регулярными выражениями в большинстве случаев не нужно, для этого есть множество [специальных библиотек](https://tproger.ru/digest/parse-html-via-php/)

Например, в вашем случае можно сделать так:

```
$dom = new \DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="utf-8" ?>' . $string);
$tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('p');

/* @var \DOMNode $tag*/
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    printf("%s\n", $tag->textContent);
}
```

Comment: И того -1 сколько уже раз говорить что парсить html не регулярками а строить dom дерево, и кто вообще плюсует такие ответы...

Comment: @Naumov )) Я с вами согласен, но вопрос про `preg_match`, а не про DOM. Регулярками тоже нужно уметь пользоваться.

Comment: @Naumov добавил в ответ ссылку на ликбез про парсинг HTML

Comment: Таких вопросов было очень много. Но регулярка это кастыль в данном случае. Да и если учесть посимвольный перебор и то что `<p>` может быть и `<P>,< p>,< p >` и как только не писаться. В конце концов всё превратиться в заторможеного монстра... Запомните регулярка нужна в крайнем случае в очень крайнем, обычно всё решаеться стоковыми и встроенными функциями.

Comment: p.s. добавьте конкретный код как решить с помощью парсера

Comment: @Naumov добавил